# Не получается вырезать

Tags: php

Не получается вырезать

```
<div class="explore"><body onload='if(top.OrphographyResult) top.OrphographyResult("","")'><base href="" /><style type="text/css">span.misspelt {background: url('/img/misspell.gif') bottom left repeat-x}</style>
```

Попытался strip_tags(), но ни чего не вырезал.

Comment: а что вырезать та нужно?

Comment: Всё что написано выше

Comment: А при чем тут strip_tags()? Вы знаете, что эта функция делает? И как я понял, этот пост - это [продолжение этой темы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/231382/php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%81-html)?

Comment: Нет это уже другое. Мне удалить из html это надо. То я  сделал

Answer (score 1):

Если всё выглядит именно так, то можно попробовать по-тупому:

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/<div class="explore">(.*)<\/style>/','',$str);
```